# Remove space between Menu links

Tags: html, css

i am relatively new and still learning. Here is my issue:

There are huge spaces between my 3 individual menu links and i can not find any solution what i am doing wrong. I also found out that the bigger the screen, the further apart these links are.

```css
.logo, .navlinks{
    display: flex;
    
}

header{
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 12vh;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo{
    
    flex: 1;

}

nav{
    
    flex: 16;
    
}

.navlinks{
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
       
   
}

.navlink{
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none; 
   
    
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h4 class="logo"> Anime Trailers </h4>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navlinks">
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Trailers</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You're using `justify-content: space-around;` on `.navlinks`. Try removing that and add margin / padding to `.navlink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the space between it, try removing the `justify-content: none;` from you css. Although It does remove all space from it, this is easily fixed by adding a space in between the words in the menu links

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked. I changed it to `justify-content: none;` and then added  `margin-left: 4vh;` to my css.